# Insertar nombre, no value de un select a mi BD

Tags: javascript, select

Tengo un formulario de actualizar, donde esta un select y puedes escoger el area si se quiere editar, al elegir cualquiera, en mi base de datos actualiza al value de la opcion.

Estos datos se llenan a travez de js, no son estaticos dentro del html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En una tabla html donde se muestran los datos, al actualizar el area, este me muestra el value 2, que corresponde a Auxitrol. Y donde necesito que se muestre la palabra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy llenando los datos en la tabla por medio de una function en js.
Y aqui es donde digo que mostrara el area.

```
var CellArea = document.createElement('td');
CellArea.innerHTML = activos[i].name_area;
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Obtener el valor del select seleccionado - Javascript - DOM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72141/obtener-el-valor-del-select-seleccionado-javascript-dom)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar .text(), no .value

Comment: Esta respuesta se beneficiaria mucho de un ejemplo práctico colega, considera realizar uno :)

Comment: Hola Macaroni, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Sería ideal que la editaras para añadir más información: ¿dónde iría el `.text()` que indicas? ¿qué es lo que hace? ¿por qué funcionaría en lugar del `.value`? Lee [answer] para más información sobre cómo mejorar tus respuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: De hecho, ya que estamos, he puesto la publicación como duplicada, ya que hay muchas respuestas en StackOverflow en español que responden su pregunta. Aquí dejo este enlace que seguro que es de utilidad:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72141/obtener-el-valor-del-select-seleccionado-javascript-dom

Comment: Con la modificación que se ha hecho en la pregunta, no la entiendo. ¿No se buscaba insertar esos valores en una BBDD? ¿Qué es "activos"?

Answer (score 0):

debes colocar el value del options como nombre no como numero:

```
<select>
  <option value="norwich">norwich</option>
  <option value="todas las areas">todas las areas</option>
  <option value="auxitrol">auxitrol</option>
  <option value="westorm">westorm</option>
</select>
```

y el base de datos cambiar el campo de int a **varchar()**;
ya esto deberia resolver tu problema!

Comment: Estoy llenando el select desde la base de datos, no los tengo asi en el html, y el tipo de dato si es varchar()

Comment: bueno debes buscar el campo name como optins ejemplo: <option value="row['name']">row['name']</option> no usar el row['id']

Answer (score 0):

Enla funcion estas usando el value no el texto:

```
 function register() { 
    //Crea Formdata para ser enviado 
    var fd = new FormData(); 
    fd.append('name_area', document.getElementById('outArea').text());
 }
```

Poniendo text tomaria como valor el texto que tenes en el option