# Error de JavaScript parseint is not defined

Tags: javascript

hace aproximadamente he estado programando esta calculadora en la que se tiene tres textboxs y un botón (por el momento es el de sumar); caja del operador 1, caja de operador 2 y la caja del resultado, ademas de utilizar funciones de javascript (sumar,restar,multiplicar y dividir), el problema es que no me lanza el resultado en la caja de texto, me pueden decir en que estoy mal on en que me estoy perdiendo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el codigo:

```js
function sumar()
  {
   var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
   var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
   var resultado = parseint(caja1) + parseint(caja2);
   document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;

  

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Calculadora</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="operaciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
 <h1>Calculadora | Manejador de nodos</h1>
 <br>
 <label>numero 1</label>
 <input type="text" name="caja1" id="caja1">
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>numero 2</label>
 <input type="text" name="caja2" id="caja2">
 <br>
 <br>
 <!-- <label>Operación</label>
 <select name="operacion" id="operacion">
  <option>Seleccione una operacion</option>
  <option type="button" onclick="sumar();">+</option>
  <option type="button" onclick="restar();">-</option>
  <option type="button" onclick="multiplicar();">*</option>
  <option type="button" onclick="dividir();">/</option>
 </select> -->
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>Resultado</label>
 <input type="text" name="resultado" id="result">
 <input type="button" onclick="sumar()" value="+">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la función es parseInt(), con mayúscula en la letra i, y lo tienes como parseint() todo minúscula.
El resto de tu código está bien. Pruébalo con esos cambios:

```
function sumar()
    {
        var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
        var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
        var resultado = parseInt(caja1) + parseInt(caja2);
        document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
    }
```

Comment: gracias compañero, pero ahora tengo otro problema :(

Comment: trate de meter todos las operaciones en un combobox y que al presionarlos te hiciera la operacion pero no funciona

Comment: poniendo en cada option un " onclick="suma()" " y asi con los demas

Comment: Seguramente te refieres al elemento select. Para el caso de este elemento no deberías usar el evento click en cada opcion, sino el evento change para el mismo select ya que el select cambiará de valor según la opción que se elija, el evento change se va a ejecutar siempre que haya un cambio. Te dejo este enlace que te va a ayudar a solucionar este problema:     https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72141/obtener-el-valor-del-select-seleccionado-javascript-dom

Answer (score 0):

La razón es que JavaScript es sensible a mayúsculas.
Has escrito `parseint()` en lugar de `parseInt()`.
Aquí la corrección:

```js
onload = function () {
  // Cajas de texto
  var 
    caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1"),
    caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2"),
    resultado = document.getElementById("result");
  
  // Botones
  var sumar = document.getElementById("sumar");
  
  sumar.onclick = function () {
    resultado.value = parseInt(caja1.value) + parseInt(caja2.value);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif, arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #606060;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[type="text"] {
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.caja {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calculadora</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="operaciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div align="center">
    <h1>Calculadora | Manejador de nodos</h1>
    <!-- Caja 1 -->
    <div class="caja caja-1">
      <label for="caja1">Número 1:</label>
      <input type="text" name="caja1" id="caja1">
    </div>

    <!-- Caja 2 -->
    <div class="caja caja-2">
      <label for="caja2">Número 2:</label>
      <input type="text" name="caja2" id="caja2">
    </div>

    <!-- Resultado -->
    <div class="resultado">
      <label for="result">Resultado:</label>
      <input type="text" name="resultado" id="result">
      
      <!-- Sumar -->
      <input type="button" id="sumar" value="+">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```